# Apache PDFBox. Преобразование PDF в PNG без корректировки содержимого

Tags: java, apache, изображения, pdf

При преобразовании PDF в PNG происходит некое преобразование содержимого документа и полученное изображение сильно отличается от оригинальной страницы.
Сэмпл кода совершенно простой.

```
        try (final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("originalDocument"))){
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
                BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
                String fileName = "c:/output/" + "image-" + page + ".png";
                ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, fileName, 300);
            }
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to create pdf document - " + e);
        }
```

Я, если правильно понимаю, он считывает текст и "перепечатывает" его в изображение. Нет ли возможности сохранить исходное содержание? Пробежался по пропертям PDFBox - ничего не нашел.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал различные PDF документы конвертировать (с картинками, текст, смешанные), никаких проблем не выявил (pdfbox 2.0.8):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"))) {
        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.png") {
            ImageIO.write(renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300), "png", out);
        }
    }
}
```